# Diameter of the tree

Tags: python, tree, recursive-datastructures

I have a code to find the diameter of the tree.
As per my understanding diameter is number of nodes in longest path between 2 leaf nodes.

The code is:

```
def diameter(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    lheight = height(root.left)
    rheight = height(root.right)

    ldiameter = diameter(root.left)
    rdiameter = diameter(root.right)
 
    return max(lheight + rheight + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter))
```

Where `height` is a function to calculate the height of the node.
However, I feel there is no need to make recursive call to `diameter` function as shown in following snippet as it gives the same output.

```
def diameter(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    lheight = height(root.left)
    rheight = height(root.right)

    return lheight + rheight + 1
```

Why are the recursive calls to `diameter` needed in the first code?

Probably, I am unable to find the case where `lheight + rheight + 1` is less than `max(ldiameter, rdiameter)`.

```py
def height(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    return 1 + max(height(node.left), height(node.right))
```

Comment: I want to know what is need of these 2 lines:
ldiameter = diameter(root.left)
rdiameter = diameter(root.right)

Comment: How is `height` defined?

Comment: Added height definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive calls to **diameter** function are needed because diameter of the tree does not necessarily pass through the root of the tree.

Your second piece of code just gives the result `height(left subtree of root) + height(right subtree of root) + 1` which will be the correct answer if diameter "path" passes through root (but not always).

An example of such tree is the 2nd tree in - [image]

In the 2nd image above, if we apply your second code, we will get result as **7** but correct answer is **9** (if we consider diameter not passing through root)